Accumulate vector using Neon and print to stdout (assembly)
I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to find good, complete examples of assembly running on Apple Silicon, specifically for SIMD-type operations, rather than incomplete, overly-generic snippets.
For my own curiosity, I want to write an example on an M2 machine that...

Takes a series of numbers (built into the assembly file, to begin with)
Accumulates them into one result (using SIMD instructions)
Output the result to stdout

I have the following source code, in a file named test.s...
.global _start
.align 2

_start:
    ;;; Load numbers into x0
    ldr x0, numbers

    ;;; Load elements from array in x0 into dedicated Neon register
    ld1 { v0. 4s }, [x0]

    ;;; Accumulate elements in vector using dedicated Neon instruction
    addv s0, v0.4s 

    ;;; Prepare formatted string
    adrp    x0, format@page
    add x0, x0, format@pageoff

    ;;; Add result to the stack for printing
    str s0, [sp, #-16]!

    ;;; Print string
    bl _printf
    mov x16, #1
    svc 0

numbers: .word 1, 2, 3, 4
format: .asciz "Answer: %u.\n"

..., assembled and linked using the following commands...
as -g -arch arm64 -o test.o test.s
ld -o test test.o -lSystem -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e _start -arch arm64

I'd have expected the answer to be 10 when I run the programme, but I get anything but.
What is it I'm not doing correctly?

Note that requests for resources are off topic, so you should focus your question, and title, on the specific code at hand. (People sometimes offer resources in answers anyway.)

Using NEON intrinsics, Apple Clang can make correct asm for macOS calling conventions and other ABI details.

Thanks, both - have edited the title to make the question more explicit.
@Peter - tried intrinsics with Xcode, but there was a lot of bloat; may try again with just clang to see if it's any different, or if there's a godbolt way then I'd try that.

ldr x0, numbers - does that get the label address?  It should load 0x0000000100000002, the first 8 bytes starting at number, as little-endian.  Siguza explains in How to load data by label on Apple Silicon (ARM64)?.  (Look for their other answers for reliably AArch64 macOS details; some things are done a little differently from AArch64 Linux, including the calling convention for variadic functions like printf passing the ... args on the stack like you're doing.)

On Godbolt, Clang -O1 -target aarch64-apple-darwin  -mcpu=apple-m1 should work.  The -target sets ABI and conventions for directives and stuff like that.  Using it with armv8 clang is most likely to have similar-enough headers installed; I don't think -target switches to a different set of headers, just tells it to compile the same sources for a different ISA / ABI.

Also, what do you mean "I get anything but"?  Do you get a segfault on the st1 { v0. 4s }, [x0] due to a bad address in x0?  A debugger should tell you.  XCode should come with lldb.  Also, that's a store, not a load.  ldr into q0 or v0.something should work.  Godbolt should show you; write a function that takes a pointer arg or loads a global array and returns a vector type.

Thanks, Peter.
I mistyped ld1 { v0.4s }, [x0] - my example uses ld1 (now corrected).
Have been trying with lldb, and can see the registers, but now just trying to interpret them from hex.

(correction to my earlier comment, ldr x0, numbers should load 0x0000000200000001, like Nate's answer says.  It is indeed little-endian, I just got the number backwards.)

ldr x0, numbers is going to load from the address labeled numbers into x0 (which only works because numbers happens to be at a sufficiently nearby address to the instruction, in the same section).  So the value in x0 will not be the address of numbers, but rather the data stored there.  You'll end up with x0 containing the value 0x0000000200000001 and the subsequent memory access will likely crash.
You should put the address of numbers into x0 with an adrp/add sequence just like you do with format further down.
Also, st1 should be ld1, as you already mentioned.
Changing these lines to
    adrp    x0, numbers@page
    add x0, x0, numbers@pageoff
    ld1 { v0.4s }, [x0]

makes the program print the correct value 10 for me.

Thanks, both - had some interesting results when running through clang, with Peter's suggestions.
;;; 16-byte align "numbers"
.p2align 4, 0x0               ; previously 2
numbers: .long 1, 2, 3, 4     ; previously .word

.global _start
.p2align 2                    ; reset alignment

_start:
    ;;; Back up x29 and x30, and move stack pointer
    sub sp, sp, #32
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    add x29, sp, #16

    ;;; Load numbers, as Nate has suggested
    adrp     x8, numbers@page

    ;;; Slightly different `ldr` approach, using q0
    ldr q0, [x8, numbers@pageoff]

    ;;; Accumulate vector
    addv.4s s0, v0

    ;;; Move 32-bit result to 32-bit GP register
    fmov w8, s0

    ;;; Store 64-bit register counterpart onto the stack for printing
    str x8, [sp]

    ;;; Prime string for printing
    adrp    x0, format@page
    add x0, x0, format@pageoff

    ;;; Print string
    bl _printf

    ;;; Prepare "return 0" from "int main()"
    mov w0, #0

    ;;; Restore x29, x30, and original stack pointer
    ldp x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    add sp, sp, #32

    ;;; "return 0"
    ret

format:
    .asciz "Answer: %u.\n"

I received the following alignment error from the linker...
ld: 'numbers' from 'assembly.o' at 0x100003F6C not 16-byte aligned, which cannot be encoded as a target of LDR/STR in '_start'+12 from 'assembly.o'
final section layout:
    __PAGEZERO           addr=0x00000000, size=0x100000000, fileOffset=0x00000000
    __TEXT               addr=0x100000000, size=0x00004000, fileOffset=0x00000000
        __text           addr=0x100003f30, size=0x0000005d, fileOffset=0x00003f30
        __stubs          addr=0x100003f90, size=0x0000000c, fileOffset=0x00003f90
        __unwind_info    addr=0x100003f9c, size=0x00000060, fileOffset=0x00003f9c
    __DATA_CONST         addr=0x100004000, size=0x00004000, fileOffset=0x00004000
        __got            addr=0x100004000, size=0x00000008, fileOffset=0x00004000
    __LINKEDIT           addr=0x100008000, size=0x00004000, fileOffset=0x00008000

..., and needed the .p2align 4, 0x0 for numbers, in order to make it work.
Interesting to see the use of ldr q0, ... instead of ld1 { v0.4s }, ... and addv.4s s0, v0 instead of addv s0, v0.4s, from the compiler.
Will need to do some more research into alignment, experimenting with other instructions, and the choice of x8 over, say, x2 or x3 (avoiding argument registers, maybe?).
Thanks again for your help.

The alignment requirement is because the offset immediate to ldr must be a multiple of the size of the object being loaded.  (The low bits of the offset are not actually encoded into the instruction and are taken to be 0 when the instruction executes.)  There is an ldur instruction which avoids this requirement, but it only allows a 9-bit immediate, whereas the full range of page offsets needs 12 bits, so it can't be used in conjunction with adrp.

It looks like the compiler missed an optimization by moving the result back to a general-purpose register before storing to the stack.

There's no particular advantage here of choosing x8 over x2 or x3, since although the latter are designated as argument registers, they aren't actually used in this function.  So it's more or less an arbitrary decision, probably an artifact of some logic within the compiler's register allocator.

And I'm not sure that it's safe to do ret from a _start entry point; I don't know whether the kernel promises for x30 to contain a useful return address.  Normally you should just invoke the exit system call directly, as your original code did.

I think addv.4s is just alternative (nonstandard?) assembler syntax for the same instruction, where the element size is just attached to the instruction mnemonic instead of the source operand.  So not a substantive difference.

Thanks for the great comments, Nate. The addv.4s, I think I remember seeing it in a previous ISA(?), but I'm fairly sure the syntax for armv8-6a is ADDV <V><d>, <Vn>.<T> (here).

And do you have any reading suggestions for the "ret" vs "svc 0" approach? The typical "Hello, world!" examples use the syscall, but most compilers seem to default to "ret".
Also, good catch on the GP register that could have been skipped - clang was run with -O1, so it might not have been applying all optimisations e.g. gcc looks to calculate "10" at compile-time, and so avoids any superfluous operations.
